# Is it possible to enable text wrapping in Intellij Idea JavaDoc tooltip?

Tags: intellij-idea, tooltip, javadoc

Intellij Idea show horizontal scroll for wide JavaDoc method declaration (preserving original text formatting on *new line*) in yellow documentation help tooltip while NetBeans IDE wrap both text and declaration to fit tooltip width.

It is annoying instead of just using Up/Down mouse scroll also move horizontal scrollbar to see hidden method arguments.

Note that today IDE practice is to extract JavaDoc from sources package and preserving text formatting by Intellij Idea is not smart, at least inconvenient...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submitted this problem to YouTrack, feel free to vote:

- [IDEA-169414](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169414) Method signature is not wrapped in JavaDoc